# flutter const constructor error

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I was following udacity course on flutter and getting error "the constructor being called isn't a const constructor" on the following line

```
const _rowHeight = 100.0;
const _cornerRadius = BorderRadius.circular(_rowHeight / 2);// error is on this line
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may simply be a bug in `border_radius.dart`.

`BorderRadius.circular` is defined as (note that the `circular` named constructor isn't `const`):

```
/// Creates a border radius where all radii are [Radius.circular(radius)].
BorderRadius.circular(double radius) : this.all(
  new Radius.circular(radius),
);
```

when it seems it could be defined as (though this may break other things):

```
/// Creates a border radius where all radii are [Radius.circular(radius)].
const BorderRadius.circular(double radius) : this.all(
  const Radius.circular(radius),
);
```

There's a workaround. Change your code to:

```
const _rowHeight = 100.0;
const _cornerRadius = BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(_rowHeight / 2));
```

Equally, you could remove the const: `var _cornerRadius =` or `BorderRadius cornerRadius =`.

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's just not possible to define a const constructors which creatse another object like that.  Another approach would be to make it static

Comment: Jonah is right, const is specially for making compile time constants which are limited by type:

"Where you declare the variable, set the value to a compile-time constant such as a number or string literal, a const variable, or the result of an arithmetic operation on constant numbers."

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const

Answer (score 1):

This might be because the widget wrapping `_cornerRadius` is a `const`. Try removing it.